# Python - Replacing integers in CSV file with a letter grade

Tags: python

So I'm in a CS class at BSU and the assignment here is to read a CSV file that contains class names, scores for those classes and how many credit hours that class is. We were told to replace the scores for the class with their appropriate letter grades but I'm struggling to figure out how? If someone knows how to easily integrate something into this to where I can replace the integers in the csv file with the letter grades than please heklp.

```
import csv

courses = []
with open("courses.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

def read_csv(file):
    courses = []
    with open(file) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='.')
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            courses.append(row)
    return courses

def print_scores():
    i=0
    file = "courses.csv"
    courses = read_csv(file)
    print("{0:10} {1:10} {2:10}".format("Course", "Score", "Cerdits"))
    for row in file:
        score = row[i][1]
        row[i][1] = grade(score)
        i += 1


def grade(score):
    if score > 100:
        grade = "Doesn't matter, ur a nurd"
    elif score >= 90:
        grade = "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        grade = "B"
    elif score >= 70:
        grade = "C"
    elif score >= 60:
        grade = "D"
    else:
        grade = "F"
    return grade
```

Comment: I would just read line by line changing the numbers to letters saving the output to a list, then overwriting the entire file with the list

Comment: you need to use csv.writer to re-save the results when you are done